# curl fails to send json parameter when the parameter is an array with new lines into a JsonResult in an MVC3 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, curl

I have an interesting situation where we have an external user calling a json method in our C# app using curl.  When the user passes the parameters without new lines it sends the content just fine.  But when there are new lines, the server doesn't receive the parameter.

Here is the command being called:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @logUsage.json http://[url]/api/venueserver/0001/logUsage
```

Here is the file contents that work:

```
{
"request": "logUsage",
"venueServerId": "5406e6e51ea59609d07a5809",
"usage": [[ "dateTime", "userId", "source", "level", "event", "message" ],[ "2014-05-02T23:39:20Z", null, "tcpServer", "usage", "connect", null ],[ "2014-05-02T23:39:21Z", "1", "tcpServer", "usage", "connect", null ],[ "2014-05-02T23:39:22Z", "1", "tcpServer", "usage", "login", "userIsFriend" ],[ "2014-05-02T23:39:23Z", "1", "tcpServer", "usage", "setChannel", "2" ],[ "2014-05-02T23:39:25Z", null, "tcpServer", "usage", "disconnect", null ]]
}
```

This is the file content that fails:

```
{
"request": "logUsage",
"venueServerId": "5406e6e51ea59609d07a5809",
"usage": [[ "dateTime", "userId", "source", "level", "event", "message" ],
[ "2014-05-02T23:39:20Z", null, "tcpServer", "usage", "connect", null ],
[ "2014-05-02T23:39:21Z", "1", "tcpServer", "usage", "connect", null ],
[ "2014-05-02T23:39:22Z", "1", "tcpServer", "usage", "login", "userIsFriend" ],
[ "2014-05-02T23:39:23Z", "1", "tcpServer", "usage", "setChannel", "2" ],
[ "2014-05-02T23:39:25Z", null, "tcpServer", "usage", "disconnect", null ]]
}
```

Here is the C# call that receives the content.

```
 public JsonResult LogUsage(string venueServerId, List<List<string>> usage)
{  
...
}
```

I have also tried it like this.

```
 public JsonResult LogUsage(string venueServerId, string usage)
 { 
---
}
```

Both scenarios will return null for the value usage even thought the other parameter is populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your exact cURL with httpbin.org/post and it worked fine with and without line breaks. According to the cURL manfile "Data is posted in a similar manner as --data-ascii does, except that newlines are preserved and conversions are never done." Try to use `--data-ascii` instead of `--data-binary`?

You can test your cURL statements against httpbin.org to check if your server or the client is the problem. See below.

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @logUsage.json httpbin.org/post`

Just curious, What OS is client running?

**EDIT: (after seeing the c# signatures)**

I don't believe you can pass json into an MVC controller method as a string so the second one will not work. The first one will work, but I've had issues with nested collections like that in the past. Usually I either go with [DynamicJson](http://pozitive.net/2011/02/04/asp-net-mvc-%E2%80%98dynamic%E2%80%99-json-jquery-templates-awesomeness/) or [DefaultModelGraphBinderCollectionExtensions](http://www.codetuning.net/blog/post/2010/02/24/Binding-Model-Graphs-with-ASPNETMVC.aspx).

Either of these solve a lot of problems.

Comment: The OS the client is running on is an Ubuntu server.  Thanks for the info.  I will try --data-ascii.  I'm also wondering if it's not on the curl side but the C# server itself not knowing how to deal with it.

Comment: Possibly. Can you share the signature of the C#/MVC method?

Comment: Yup.  I added the signature above.